# How to better catch/do/empty with RXJS 5.5.2 Updates

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, rxjs5

As staten in the ionic-angular 3.9.0 release notes (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), using the advantages of updating to RXJS 5.5.2 could reduce the bundle size and therefore lead to a faster boot time

Cool, cool, cool :)

The example provided by Ionic, to migrate for example `debounceTime` is pretty clear, I get it.

But it's pretty unclear to me how I should update my following code to take the full advantage of this RXJS update.

Anyone could help me to convert it or how to better write it with the goal to save bundle size?

```
 import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
 import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(req).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            // do stuff with response if you want
        }
    }).catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if ((err.status == 400) || (err.status == 401)) {
            this.interceptorRedirectService.getInterceptedSource().next(err.status);
            return Observable.empty();
        } else {
            return Observable.throw(err);
        }
    })
}
```

P.S.: Linked post https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-better-catch-do-empty-with-rxjs-5-5-2-updates/111559

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I came up with the following updated code which still works (tested it).

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty';
import {tap} from 'rxjs/operators/tap';
import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators/catchError';

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):   Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

       return next.handle(req).pipe(
        tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                // do stuff with response if you want
            }
        }),
        catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if ((err.status == 400) || (err.status == 401)) {
                this.interceptorRedirectService.getInterceptedSource().next(err.status);
                return Observable.empty();
            } else {
                return Observable.throw(err);
            }
        })
    );
}
```

Note:

- Lettable operators have to be imported with a full import path to reduce the bundle size

  Good: import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators/catchError';
  Bad:  import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';
- Static doesn't change respectively they are not lettable (see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3059)
- Static could be only imported once in app.component.ts for the all app (this won't reduce the bundle size but the code will be cleaner)

Comment: Lettable imports depend on webpack configurations to use deep or not.

 unable to upgrade to Webpack 3+.Therefore importing from rxjs/operators will likely make your application bundle larger. However, there's still a way you can use lettable operators. You will have to use deep imports, similar to how you import prior to version 5.5 and lettable.
`
import { map, filter, reduce } from 'rxjs/operators';
becomes:

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators/filter';
import { reduce } from 'rxjs/operators/reduce'; `

Answer (score 3):

Building upon the excellent answer from David Dal Buscon, I've also updated **Observable.empty** and **Observable.throw** to **empty** and **_throw** respectively

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {empty} from 'rxjs/observable/empty';
import {_throw} from 'rxjs/observable/throw';
import {catchError, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):       
  Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req)
      .pipe(
        tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            // do stuff with response if you want
          }
        }),
        catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          if ((err.status == 400) || (err.status == 401)) {                         
            this.interceptorRedirectService.getInterceptedSource()
              .next(err.status);
            return empty();
          }

          return _throw(err);
        })
     );
}
```

Comment: Or `import { ErrorObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';` and `ErrorObservable.create(err)`.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 17 here, RxJS 7.8.1. Since all of the answers are pretty much deprecated here, this is what I did to return an empty Observable:

```
import { catchError, EMPTY } from 'rxjs';

  test(): void {
    this.testService
      .startTestJob()
      .pipe(
        catchError((err) => {
          this.snackIt.addError('error:', err);
          return EMPTY;
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```