# How to intercept response that is non JSON

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using Angular 5.1.0 and am trying to read file sent from server as a response to a GET request.

I am doing so:

```
  getImage(imageUrl: string) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + this.authService.getBasicAuthString(),
        resourceType: 'blob'
      })
    };
    return this.http.get<File>(imageUrl, httpOptions);
  }
```

BUT, as it seems, the bug that is marked as fixed [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19103) is not fixed for 5.1.0 and am constantly receiving HttpErrorResponse saying that it can not parse the received response (the reponse code is 200).

What I am trying is to rewrite the workaround provided in the bug for 5.1.0, but the community there isn't very responsive.

The workaround is:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).catch(event => {
      if (event instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        const response = event as HttpErrorResponse;
        if (response.headers.get('content-type') === 'application/json') {
          return Observable.throw(new HttpErrorResponse({
            error: JSON.parse(response.error),
            headers: response.headers,
            status: response.status,
            statusText: response.statusText,
            url: response.url,
          }));
        }
      }
      return Observable.throw(event);
    })
}
```

It looks good, but the problem is as follows: 
`Property 'catch' does not exist on type Observable<HttpEvent<any>>`.

Can someone help me with that, because I am not that much of Angular guru.

**UPDATE after Ritwick Dey's answer (I am leaving the first part unanswered, because it may appear to someone else, that is not that good with that stuff as a question):**

Now, as everything is found, I need not to throw and just pass all other interceptors and to return a raw response to the subscriber of my GET method. I don't want a throw, because it comes, again, as error with the same message:

```
message: "Http failure during parsing for **logo-url**"
​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
```

I want to use of(), as mentioned [here](https://v5.angular.io/guide/http#caching), but i get the following error when replacing **return Observable.throw(event);** with **return of(req);**:

```
ERROR in src/app/shared/parser.interceptor.ts(16,5): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{} | HttpProgressEvent | HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpResponse<any> | Http...' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>'.
  Type '{} | HttpProgressEvent | HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<a...' is not assignable to type 'HttpEvent<any>'.
    Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'HttpEvent<any>'.
      Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'HttpUserEvent<any>'.
        Property 'type' is missing in type '{}'.
src/app/shared/parser.interceptor.ts(31,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'of'.
```

OF is imported with the following clause:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45483934/how-to-correctly-import-operators-from-the-rxjs-package

Answer (score 1):

Have you imported `catch` operator from rxjs ?

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'
```

If you're using Rxjs 5.5, follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47203943/6120338

Comment: Good catch, I will update my answer with following problems :)